# Integer promotion and right shifting

Tags: c

Considering that for example an unsigned char will always be promoted to an int can I assume that if I don't cast to unsigned char before shifting the result will always be implementation defined?

For example:

```
unsigned char c = 0x0F;
unsigned int a = c >> 2;
```

Here **c** will be promoted to an int before shifting to the right. So the shifting will be implementation defined, depending on the compiler.

The right way would be:

```
unsigned int a = (unsigned char)c >> 2;
```

My question being, is this statement true:

**Doing any shifting on any datatype smaller than int will be implementation defined if not also cast to unsigned type?**

Comment: *I don't cast the unsigned char to unsigned char* - hm. Cast what to what?

Comment: `c >> 2` is the very same as `(unsigned char)c >> 2`

Comment: No, it will never be implementation defined, because casting unsigned char to int will never produce a negative int, and shifting on signed, but not negative integrals is well defined.

Comment: "unsigned char will always be promoted to an int" --> Most often.  Could promote to `unsigned` when `unsigned char` range exceeds `int` range.  See [@dbush comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898140/integer-promotion-and-right-shifting#comment90748146_51898265).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result will always be well defined.

A right shift of a signed type is only implementation defined *if the value is negative*.  This is specified in section 6.5.7p5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Bitwise shift operators:

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has
>   an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value,
>   the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 /
>   2<sup>E2</sup>. If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value
>   is implementation-defined.

The value also cannot be negative because integer promotions preserve the sign of the value being promoted.  From section 6.3.1.1p3 regarding conversion of integers:

> The integer promotions preserve value including sign. As discussed
>   earlier, whether a "plain" char is treated as signed is
>   implementation-defined.

So because the value is guaranteed to be positive, the right shift operation is well defined.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do I need to look out for 1's to appear in the msb when shifting right in regards to integer promotion?

Comment: If the original type is as unsigned type, then no.  Section 6.3.1.1p2 states "*If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned
int*".  So the promoted type could be `unsigned int` if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, integer promotion really makes my head hurt and I start imagining all sort of problems that evidently doesn't exist. :)

Comment: This is exactly the behavior I'd like but, this sure has the flavor of a tax loophole

Answer (score 0):

[6.5.7p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p3) on Bitwise Shift Operations says:

> ```
> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.
> ```

If you have a subint type on the left side (or right side, but there it doesn't really matter) of a bitshift operations, it'll be promoted to `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p3
#define TPSTR(X) _Generic(X,unsigned char: "uchar", int: "int")
    unsigned char c = 0x0F;
    printf("%s\n", TPSTR(c>>2));
    printf("%s\n", TPSTR((unsigned char)c>>2));
    printf("%s\n", TPSTR((unsigned char)c>>(unsigned char)2));
}
```

compiles and prints `int int int`.

The result of a right-shift on a signed integer type (int) will only be implementation defined iff the left operand has a negative value:

[6.5.7p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p5):

> If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is
>   implementation-defined.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.